# SceneKit get current SCNNode position form Animated SCNNode

Tags: macos, cocoa, scenekit, caanimation, scnnode

I want to get a current node position form an animated `SCNNode`
I am aware of `presentationNode` and I tried to extract position form there, but no Luck

Here is my Code

```
SCNNode * pelvis = [_unit childNodeWithName:@"Bip01_Pelvis" recursively:YES];
SCNNode * present = pelvis.presentationNode;



SCNVector3 position = [self convertPosition:present.position toNode:self.parentNode];
```

The position I have is the position of the `SCNNode` in the "rest" mode before the `CAAnimation` was applied.

How to get properties like position form the 'presentationNode'?

**Edit**

Class itself relevant parts:

```
@interface UndeadSimple : RepresentationNode <CAAnimationDelegate>
{
    //Animations
    SCNNode * _undead;

    CAAnimation * _currentAnimation;
    NSString    * _currAnimationkey;

    CAAnimation * _death1;
    ...

    SCNNode        * _audioNode;
    SCNAudioSource * _deathSource;
    SCNAudioPlayer * _player;
}
```

Init:

```
NSString * sceneName = @ZOMBIE;
SCNScene *scene2 = [SCNScene sceneNamed:sceneName];

_undead = [SCNNode node];
for(SCNNode * node in scene2.rootNode.childNodes)
{
    [_undead addChildNode:node];
    [node removeAllAnimations];
}
[_undead setScale:(SCNVector3Make(0.024, 0.02, 0.024))];

[self addChildNode:_undead];
[_undead removeAllAnimations];

_currentAnimation = _idleAnimation;
_currAnimationkey = @"resting";

[_undead addAnimation:_currentAnimation forKey:_currAnimationkey];
```

Animation and event:

```
SCNAnimationEvent * event2 = [SCNAnimationEvent animationEventWithKeyTime:0.9 block:^(CAAnimation * _Nonnull animation, id  _Nonnull animatedObject, BOOL playingBackward)
{
    [self.delegate finishedDeathAnimation];
}];

_death1 = anims.death1.mutableCopy;
[_death1 setDelegate:self];
[_death1 setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
_death1.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[_death1 setAnimationEvents:@[event2]];
```

Animation Call:

```
- (void)die
{

    if([_currAnimationkey isEqualToString:@"dead"])
    {
        return;
    }

   [_undead removeAllAnimations];
   CAAnimation * death = nil;



    int anim = arc4random_uniform(3);
    if(anim < 1)
    {
        death = _death1;
    }
    else if(anim < 2)
    {
        death = _death2;
    }
    else
    {
        death = _death3;
    }

    _currAnimationkey = @"dead";
    _currentAnimation = death;
```

}

//Helper Method to get presentation Node

```
- (SCNNode *)getSnapNode
{
    SCNNode * repNode = [_undead presentationNode];
    _undead.transform = repNode.transform;
    repNode = _undead.clone;
    return repNode;
}
```

//On callback call and try to get position:

```
- (void)finishedDeathAnimation
{
    SCNPlane * bloodgeometry = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:4 height:4];
    bloodgeometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [NSImage imageNamed:@"blood"];

    SCNNode * bloodNode = [SCNNode node];
    [bloodNode setEulerAngles:SCNVector3Make(-M_PI_2, 0, 0)];
    bloodNode.geometry = bloodgeometry;

    //Bip01_Pelvis
    SCNNode * deadBody = [_unit getSnapNode];

    SCNNode * pelvis = [deadBody childNodeWithName:@"Bip01_Pelvis" recursively:YES];

    SCNNode * present = pelvis.presentationNode;
    SCNVector3 position = [self convertPosition:present.position toNode:self.parentNode];

   NSLog(@"pelvis position %lf,%lf,%lf", present.position.x, present.position.y, present.position.z); //Always {0,0,0}


    bloodNode.position = SCNVector3Make(position.x, 0.0001, position.z);

    [self.parentNode addChildNode:bloodNode];

    [self removeFromParentNode];
}
```

***Edit 2***

I also tried to simplify it a bit:

another helper method:

//in undead/unit class

```
- (SCNVector3)getPosition
{
    SCNNode * repNode = [[_undead childNodeWithName:@"Bip01_Pelvis" recursively:YES] presentationNode];
    return repNode.position;
}
```

On callback:

```
- (void)finishedDeathAnimation
{
    position = [_unit getPosition];
    NSLog(@"pelvis position %lf,%lf,%lf", position.x, position.y, position.z); //Alway 0,0,0 as well :(
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rare to find someone just like me still believe in Objective C rather than swift thats why i would like to offer full help.

I was having this issue for an animation exported from Blender as a Collada but have succeeded to get the actual position after few tries.

Using presentationNode is the correct way but you need to get it from the child while you making the animation for example this is how to run animation for a node Called _monkey  notice that at the last Code i got the _present From the child.presentationNode Not from _monkey.presentationNode Also it have to be obtained during the enumeration not after

so first i need to define

```
NSNode * _present;
```

then i do play the animation

```
   [_monkey enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock:^(SCNNode *child, BOOL *stop)
     {
         for(NSString *key in child.animationKeys)
         {               // for every animation key
             CAAnimation *animation = [child animationForKey:key]; // get the animation
             animation.usesSceneTimeBase = NO;                     // make it system time based
             animation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;                      // make it repeat forever
             animation.speed = 0.2;
             [child addAnimation:animation forKey:key];            // animations are copied upon addition, so we have to replace the previous animation
         }
         _present = child.presentationNode;
     }];
```

Then Under the render i can check the Results which is changing as the animation moves (Also if you have worked with iOS11 you can check worldPosition instead of position it gives great results too).

```
- (void)renderer:(id <SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
{
     NSLog(@" Location X:%f Y:%f Z:%f", _present.position.x, _present.position.y, _present.position.z);

}
```

Finally Here Is The Results

```
Y:-2.505034 Z:4.426160
2017-10-11 04:42:19.700435+0200 monkey[547:137368]  Location X:-5.266642 Y:-2.480119 Z:4.427162
2017-10-11 04:42:19.720763+0200 monkey[547:137368]  Location X:-5.215315 Y:-2.455228 Z:4.428163
2017-10-11 04:42:19.740449+0200 monkey[547:137346]  Location X:-5.163589 Y:-2.430143 Z:4.429171
2017-10-11 04:42:19.760397+0200 monkey[547:137368]  Location X:-5.112190 Y:-2.405216 Z:4.430173
2017-10-11 04:42:19.780557+0200 monkey[547:137346]  Location X:-5.060925 Y:-2.380355 Z:4.431173
2017-10-11 04:42:19.800418+0200 monkey[547:137342]  Location X:-5.008560 Y:-2.355031 Z:4.432024
```

This Give Me Good Results. Hope it would work with you.

Answer (score 1):

There's no animation running, at least not in the code you've shown us. Check the presentation node's position while the animation is playing, perhaps in `renderer:updateAtTime:` (see SCNRendererDelegate).

Comment: I ensure you that animation is running, I made an SCNAnimationEvent to get the delegate when it os near the end - and tried to extract posion from the presentation node - but it always returns SCNVectorZero :-(

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the code that you are actually using, including the code that launches the animation. The timing and sequencing of this stuff matters and you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Mr. Hal, I edited my Question and added almost all the relevant code

Comment: Well I just gave up, I will export DAE from Max in the needed position - sad very sad :(. Generally I think SceneKit team should rework the animations - make it more sensible for game development and optimise it somehow, because for now animations take 80% of my loop time which forces me to make all my update logic in less than 2ms and it is terrible.

Comment: Your clone of the presentation node looks dodgy to me. But I haven't had time to investigate deeply. Please file a Radar!!

Comment: Yeah it is a product of 999 tries to solve the issue :-) , thus I created the more simple method to return the position - which fires the same results :(